# UISearchBar via rails request

Tags: swift

I am trying to pull back search results via rails request and right now my code doesn't crash. However, it also does not pull back any search results.

How do I get it to show the search results in the search bar?

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

     dismissKeyboard()

    if !searchBar.text!.isEmpty {
        if dataTask != nil {
            dataTask?.cancel()
        }


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true


    let APIbaseURL = "https://flour-power.herokuapp.com"

    func recipeSearchAPI(_: String) {

    var info = RequestInfo()
    info.endpoint = "/api/recipes/search?query=:search_terms"
    info.method = .GET


    func requiredWithInfo(info: RequestInfo, completion: (returnedInfo: AnyObject?) -> ()) {

        let fullURLString = APIbaseURL + info.endpoint

        guard let url = NSURL(string: fullURLString) else { return }

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

        request.HTTPMethod = info.method.rawValue

        dataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL(url) {
            data, response, error in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            }

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                self.updateSearchResults(data)
            }
        }
    }

    dataTask?.resume()

    }

}


}

    if(filtered.count == 0){

        searchActive = false

    } else {

        searchActive = true
    }

    self.webSearchTV.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search request is malformed. Instead of

```
info.endpoint = "/api/recipes/search?query=:search_terms"
```

you need something like

```
if let queryString = searchBar.text
{
    info.endpoint = String(format: "/api/recipes/search?query=%@", queryString) 
}
```